# How to change the width of jbox-image-gallery?

Tags: javascript, width, gallery, jbox

i have a problem!
I'm using j-box for a gallery in my site, but the js set default width(800) and height(563). Everything it's ok when I use 800x600px images. But when I use 600x800px images, these are cut in order to occupy the 800x600 space.
Can i modify this:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        new jBox('Image', {
            width: 800,
            height: 563
        });
    });
</script>
```

and set as width the images' width, and the same for height?

I'm sorry for my bad english.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The images are cut because the default setting of the option imageSize is 'cover'.

You can set it to 'contain' or 'auto' or any other background-size value, read more about that here: http://stephanwagner.me/jBox/options under section "Additional options for type Image"

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        new jBox('Image', {
            width: 800,
            height: 600,
            imageSize: 'contain'
        });
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

try

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        new jBox('Image', {
            width: auto,
            height: auto
        });
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you guys. With 'auto' the image container is like 0x0. With imageSize:'contain' it's perfect. Problem solved!